# Trying to create tables with hibernate and java spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a `User` class and a `Recipe` class. The `Recipe` class has a field which shows which user owns what recipe. And the User has an id. I think this should be a `ManyToOne` connection because one user can have many recipes. My question his, how can I code this in Java spring, with these annotations I find myself a little lost. This is what I've come up with but it doesn't work.

```
@Entity
public class Recipe {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int recipe_id;
    private String name;
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id" , table="User")
    private int user_id;
    private LocalDate dateUploaded;
    private String description;

    public int getId() {
        return recipe_id;
    }

    public void setId(int recipe_id) {
        this.recipe_id = recipe_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getUser() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser(int user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public LocalDate getDateUploaded() {
        return dateUploaded;
    }

    public void setDateUploaded(LocalDate dateUploaded) {
        this.dateUploaded = dateUploaded;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

And the User class

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int user_id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String userName;
    private String password;

    public User(int user_id, String firstName, String lastName, String userName, String password, int[] favoriteRecipes, int[] myRecipes) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setId(int user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about the associations in the question or you want to add a list property in the users class which have all the recipes uploaded by the user? Making the association bidirectional.

Comment: No we don't want to have a list, because then we brake 1st Normal form.

Answer (score 0):

```
You should add one more field in user table that is getRecieps and add this annotation.  

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "USER_RECEIPE", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "receipe_id") })

   public Set<receipe> getReceipes() {
        return this.receipes;
    }

    public void setreceipes(Set<receipe> receipes) {
        this.receipes= receipes;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are trying to achieve ManyToOne relation between `Recipe` and `User`.

All you need to do is add below annotation to the `user_id` field in

**Recipe class**

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
private int user_id;
```

Try this and let me know if you still face issues.

Comment: When I do the ManyToOne annotations or other annotations in that region, and include (name="user_id", table="User") in the JoinColumn then I get the error  :Cannot find the expected secondary table: no User available for com.einar.inthefridge.model.Recipe

Comment: Cross check the table names, you should have tables with name `user` and `recipe` since you have not explicitly mentioned table name in the entity class files